# For ruby files, can SublimeText 3 be configured to such that "goto declaration" works based on the imports?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

Let's say I'm editing a **ruby project** and have a ruby script open.

There's some function that I would like to lookup. So I right-click on the function and choose "goto declaration".

```
require "path\Object1"
@obj = Object1.new()
@obj.method1ThatReturnsObj.method2.method3
```

I right-click on method2 and choose "goto declaration".

What currently happens is that SublimeText seems to perform a **search for all definitions** of "method2" throughout the project. This results in a list of definition options which I need to sort through until I finally arrive at the correct file.

In other words, there are **multiple class files that have the same method name**. I haven't imported those classes in my script. But when I try "goto declaration", then even those would show up on my list.

**Is there a way to get ST 3, to check the current imports, and then find the declaration only among those imported files?**

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags

Answer (score 0):

Is there a built-in way to do what you want? No, not to my knowledge.

You could take a look at the goto definition source code (written in Python) and modify it to perform what you are asking for: https://bitbucket.org/klorenz/sublimegotodefinition/src